# Counting number of 'x' letter words

Tags: java, string

I now have this code which if for example I enter the words 'how are you', it will output '3 3 3' however I want to edit my code so that it outputs that there are 3 '3' letter words, how can I do this?

```
 import java.util.*;

    public final class CountLetters {

      public static void main (String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String words = sc.nextLine();

        String[] letters = words.split(" ");

        for (String str1 : letters) 

        {
        System.out.println(str1.length() ); 
        }


      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a HashMap for this.

```
public static void main(String[]args){

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  String bubba = input.nextLine();



  Map<Integer,Integer> occurrences = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>(); 

  for(String currentWord: bubba.split(" ")){
      Integer current = occurrences.get(currentWord.length());
      if(current==null){
          current = 0;
      }

      occurrences.put(currentWord.length(), current+1);
  }

  for(Integer currentKey: occurrences.keySet()){
      System.out.println("There are "+occurrences.get(currentKey)+" "+currentKey+" letter words");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an array of `int`s to keep track of the count of each word length.

For each word, increment the value in your array corresponding to the word's length.

At the end, go through your int array and print out how many words of each length were found. For this step, you should add a condition so it only prints if the count is > 0.

Comment: If you know the longest possible word length from the input, let that be your array size. If not, you can read through the input twice, once to determine the longest word, then a second time to count all lengths. A third option is to use a map, where the key is the word length, and the value is the count of words that long.